# Having a space after id name in jQuery '#id ' selects all the elements

Tags: jquery

I completely understand that ID must be unique as per the W3C specification, but if there are multiple elements with same id in a page, then

`$('#a')` : selects the first element with id = a in the DOM

`$('#a ')` : selects all the elements with id = a

I am not using any of this in my code, but only interested in finding out why does having a space after id name selects all the elements? 
Is this intentional or just a bug or an edge case due to W3C violation?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3cxjkwh/

Comment: @pranav I have linked a jsfiddle.. can u test it

Comment: I'm guessing the space might make jquery think it's a more complex query that just an id, so it doesn't use getElementById and ence get more. But ids should be unique anyway so your example is an invalid case.

Comment: The "bug" would be repeating IDs.

Comment: If jQuery finds a valid ID selector it will use `document.getElementById()` which returns 1 result. Otherwise (this case) it uses a query selector, which returns all ID matches.

Comment: ID should be unique in same document, thanks.